# Using/handling bitcoin in Unity3d game

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity-game-engine, bitcoin

I need to handle bitcoin in my unity project

I tried to install some nuget packages to support that

like this for example : https://github.com/blockchain/api-v1-client-csharp

but I always get this error

> Could not install package 'BlockchainAPI 2.0.0'. You are trying  to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0',  but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are  compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

unfortunately - no current unity3d plugins that support bitcoin yet

any suggestions , solutions ?

Comment: The API does not support .Net 4.0, you could try to upgrade the .csproj manually

Comment: I am assuming you want to use bitcoin for payments? You could implement the bitcoin processing server side and have your game client talk with it instead of implementing it directly.

Comment: @MSB , yes I want to use bitcoin for transferring money in my game
-- how to implement the bitcoin processing server side and what that mean , can you explain more please , I did not get it

Comment: What I suggested was basically writing a web server with a .NET backend that implements your bitcoin API, you could then use a web socket to talk from the game to your web server. This is however complicated to do if you have never done so before. The answer suggested by @Programmer would also work and is probably easier if you have little experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin is using .NET version that is > Unity's supported .NET version.

The easiest solution I know about is to download the project directly from the link you posted.Delete any file that is **NOT** a C# file(`.cs`). Extract those folders with the remaining files and put them in your Unity project. Now look for errors. If you find any script with an error or script that uses **C# 4** classes, modify it and fix the errors by hand.

This is easier than trying to implement your own bitcoin API from scratch.

**NOTE**: The only reason I recommend this method is because I looked inside the project and there were no `DLL` files inside it. So it is possible to port it if there is no `DLL` file in the API. Assuming there were `DLL` files compile with **C# 4**, then that would be a problem.

Comment: @AhmedMohsen You are not building a rocket, so the world won't end if you try it and make a mistake. I can't answer that question until you try it and see for yourself. I've done something similar like this. It was a huge API and took 2 days to port for Unity but it worked. As long as there is no DLL for the  API, the chances of it working is high.

Answer (score 1):

[There's a beta edition of Unity](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/upgraded-mono-net-in-editor-on-5-5-0b4.433541/) that now supports a newer Mono version, which can let you compile .NET 4.5.2 (or older) projects.

I recommend you [Nicolas Dorier's NBitcoin library](https://github.com/metacosa/nbitcoin) for this then.

Comment: The first part of this answer is **not** correct. I've been following the .NET 4.5>= beta for a long time and it is not yet ready. The run-time API is not ready and is not released.  .NET 4.5 will **only** work in the Editor not in any standalone build.

Comment: if it's not "yet ready" please paste the link to the bug reports that you opened

Comment: Instead of just posting "Unity now supports new Mono version", why not read the post made by Unity in the link you posted. Don't just post random link. It says Editor only! Please read that blog. Also, speaking about bugs, there are few filed for this which are not fixed. I don't post links for bug reports for privacy reasons. Not just me, many other testers found few problems with the new compiler and we filed for bug. That's  why it's not released yet.

Comment: of course it's not released yet, it says it's a beta; but it's a better answer for this stackoverflow question because removing C#4 features now is overkill given that Mono4.6 support in Unity is around the corner

Comment: I don't think you understand my point. My point is that it will only work in the Editor. What's the point of using it if it works it won't work in any build? So, OP would have to tell his clients to download Unity Editor in order to use his app?  Do you know the difference between Editor and Standalone? Anyways, this whole comment is about your first sentence.  The link to the other library is helpful,useful and should solve OP's problem if the problem is still there. The statement about  .NET 4.5.2 support is incorrect as you can't use it in a build. Happy coding!

Comment: well you have a fair point about me not knowing the difference between Editor and Standalone (never used Unity TBH) but I very much doubt that they leave the new Mono version only available for the Editor and not for everything else, when it becomes stable and officially supported